# How to use the UInavigationcontroller animation with library Motion?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I came across a library call Motion on GitHub which provide sets of transition on view and controllers.
Based on the website, to use the animation on navigation controller we need to create a new navigation controller class like below, and I apply the new navigation controller. But when it failed and not pushing to the new view controller.

the GitHub link is https://github.com/CosmicMind/Motion

```
class AppNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        isMotionEnabled = true
        motionNavigationTransitionType = .zoom
    }
}
```

then on the main view:

```
let navigation = AppNavigationController()
navigation.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `Motion`'s animated `NavigationController` throughout your app, you can set it this way in your `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
let newViewController = NewViewController(nibName: "NewViewController",bundle: nil)
let navigation = AppNavigationController(rootViewController: newViewController!)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigation
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**UPDATE:** 
If you want to create a separate `NavigationController` and push specific `UIViewController` to it, then you need to **present** the navigation controller instead of pushing it. See below.

```
let motionNavController = AppNavigationController(rootViewController: galleryViewController)
motionNavController.motionNavigationTransitionType = .none
motionNavController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
self.present(motionNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can I just make specific viewcontroller and navigate with the transition? Your method is not really suitable for me is because my rootviewcontroller is not programatically created

Comment: In that case, you should be presenting the NavigationController instead of pushing it. Only UIViewControllers can be pushed. Check the code below.                                        
let motionNavController = AppNavigationController(rootViewController: newViewController)
        motionNavController.motionNavigationTransitionType = .none
        motionNavController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.present(motionNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)